# How can I apply Gradient on SVG Polyline using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to create a graph, with two lines showing two different progresses. So, I am using div SVG Polyline & Line function to achieve it. Sample code is here :

```
var svgGraph = SVG("divID");
//Polyline
var p = svgGraph.polyline(myXYDataArray);
p.fill('#color').attr({
    'stroke': '#color',
    'stroke-width': '5px'
});
// Straight line
var straighLine = svgGraph.line(0, 150, 300, 450);
straighLine.fill('none').attr({
    'stroke': '#color',
    'stroke-width': '5px'
});
```

Note : 
I am using tag-:div to place graph, something like : 
 `<div id="divId"></div>`

I want to apply gradient on lower par of the line, if I apply 'fill:"#color", it will gonna apply on top of polyline. So, can someone help me how can I achieve this. 
Attaching image for clarification : 
[image: White line shows where I need gradient]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to define a closed shape that defines the area between the two lines. Then apply the gradient to that.